# Can I preset targetSdk while creating new project in Android Studio Dolphin?

Tags: android-studio

During the installation of Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1.17 the SDK platform 33 is default.

[Default SDK platform image]

Next when I try to create a new project, its default target SDK is 32, so it starts downloading SDK platform 32 automatically.

[SDK downloading image]

Then IDE recommends to upgrade SDK platform version to 33.

[Highlighted problem image]
[Problem description image]

I think the IDE is acting strange.

Can I choose specific target SDK while(before) creating a new projects?
Can I choose specific default SDK version during Android Studio installation?

Thank you!

Comment: you mention 3 images in your question. Zero of them are visible.

Comment: More precisely, 4 images. It turns out I need at last 10 scores to post images.